# Meaning of "closed under composition"

Tags: haskell, applicative

I have been reading [this paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) and it is mentioned there that the `Applicative` class is closed under composition.

What does that actually mean ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In general, "X is closed under Y" means that if you take some Xs and Y them, the result is an X. For example, "the set of integers is closed under addition" means that if you take two integers and add them, the result is an integer.

Therefore, saying that the class `Applicative` is closed under composition means that if you take two applicative functors and compose them, the result is also an applicative functor.

Answer (score 12):

The composition of `Applicative`s `f` and `g` is

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

and "`Applicative` is closed under composition" means that this `newtype` itself has an `Applicative` instance.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html